# How to compare two 802.15.4 O-QPSK modulated digitals signals?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, modulation, qpsk

I am working on wireless sensors project and I am trying to simulate a transmission between two nodes.

So let's say I have two nodes which transmit the message to each other, i.e. node 1 transmits to node 2 and then node 2 transmits to node 1. 
Let's say the message being transmitted is exactly the same and the difference between the packets is just Source/Destination Address as well as Frame Check Sequence Field(FCS) of MPDU. The message is being generated and encoded into signal wave.

Now, without demodulation process and  is there any way to distinguish two signals and see if it comes from node 1 or node 2 by looking only at the waveforms of transmitted signals? Observer sees signals separately, i.e. they are not mixed and come to receiver one after another with short interval in time between them. So it is basically to classify them as "signal 1" and "signal different from signal 1". Is there also a way to extract bits from the signal ?

For example possibly  by converting it to frequency domain by looking at the amplitude or phase spectrum of the signal? 
Or may be it is achievable after certain number of iterations so enough data can be sampled and thus pattern can be drawn?

Please share your ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you trying to identify whether a given signal is coming from node 1 or from node 2, without demodulating it?

Comment: @MBaz yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ViniLL then you're more or less analyzing two things: a) the physical differences between these senders, (which should be relatively small, so hard to detect), b) the properties of the different two channels. See: blind source estimation, MIMO techniques.

Comment: As @MarcusMüller suggests, your best bet is probably trying to identify the two channels between the two nodes and the observer.

Comment: @Marcus Müller thanks for suggestion, however for BSS I do not have mixture of signals, I have only one receiver and two signals which are not transmitted at the same time, there is short interval between message 1 and message 2 is captured by receiver. Will BSS will still address my problem in this case?

Comment: depends – can't say.